# Equivelance relation problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$ \mathbb{R}^2 ((x,y),(u,v)) \in R \leftrightarrow x+v = y+ u $$
Question is, whether there is equivalance relation.
I know that I should check for reflectivity, symmetry and transitivity.

Is this correct?

Check for reflectivity:
$$ ((x,y), (x,y)) \in R \leftrightarrow  x+y = y + x $$
This is correct because adding is commutative

Checking for symmetry:
$$((x,y), (y,x)) \in R \leftrightarrow x+x = y+y $$
That is not correct, therefore there is no equivelance relation.

Comment: No, what you are calling surjectivity is not a requirement for an equivalence relation.

Comment: I edited the mistake.

Comment: No no. You don't need $(x,y)$ to be related to $(y,x)$. Have a look at @vadim123's post.

Comment: vilbur: Don't forget to accept answers that are helpful. To accept an answer, just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it, and you receive two reputation points for each accepted answer. You can, however, only accept one answer per question asked. But you can also upvote $(\uparrow)$ as many helpful answers as you'd like!

Answer (score 3):

What you need to check is not surjectivity, but symmetry.  Assume that $(x,y)R(z,w)$, then prove that $(z,w)R(x,y)$.  Or, using the ordered pair notation, assume that $((x,y),(z,w))\in R$, and prove that $((z,w),(x,y))\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 3rd approach : You say that $(x,y) \sim (u,v)$ iff $x+v = y+u$, but this is that same as saying
$$
y - x = v-u
$$
which is the same as saying

> $(x,y) \sim (u,v)$ iff $\exists c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that both points like on the same line given by the equation
>   $$
> y = x+c
> $$

Now what does the definition of an equivalence relation require?

a) Reflexivity : Clearly a point lies on the same line as itself

b) Symmetry : If $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ lie on the same line, then .. they lie on the same line!

c) Transitivity : If $z_1$ and $z_2$ lie on the same line (as above), and $z_2$ and $z_3$ lie on the same line, then the constant $c$ must be the same for both pairs, and so $z_1$ and $z_3$ lie on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about reflectivity.

Checking for symmetry: suppose that $(x,y)R(u,v)$. We have $x+v = y+u $.

Now, is $(u,v)R(x,y)$ ? i.e do we have $u+y =x+v$? Well, yes since this is precisely our hypothesis.

Check for transitivity : suppose that $(x,y)R(u,v)$ and that $(u,v)R(w,z)$. We have

$$x+v = y+u$$ and $$u+z = w + v.$$

Now, is $(x,y)R(w,z)$ ? i.e. do we have $x+z = w+y$ ? Let's do a bit of algebra :

$$ x + z = x + (w+v-u) = w + (x+v-u) = w + y.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

Note that $(x,y)R(u,v)$ **iff** $x-y = u-v$. In particular, letting $f((a,b)) = a-b$, we see that $(x,y)R(u,v)$ **iff** $f((x,y)) = f((u,v))$.

Since equality is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$, it follows immediately that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To see, we have $f((x,y)) = f((x,y))$, hence $R$ is reflexive, if $f((x,y)) = f((u,v))$, then $f((u,v)) = f((x,y))$, hence $R$ is symmetric, and if $f((x,y)) = f((u,v))$ and $f((u,v)) = f((a,b))$, then clearly $f((x,y)) = f((a,b))$, hence transitive.